# постоянная работа функции которая асинхронно получает данные из базы данных

Tags: javascript, php

В своем проэкте я имею функцию `getNewMessages()` которая получает новые данные из БД.
Она работает следующим образом: на странице сайта у меня есть таблица в которую я помещаю новые сообщения из базы данных. Из первого сообщения в таблице я передаю айди(`lastId`) в функцию и если есть сообщения с `id > lastId` то передаю такие данные через `file.php` в функцию и высветляю новые сообщения в таблице.
Теперь важно понимать: `getNewMessages()` у меня всегда работает с помощью функции `setInterval()` и асинхронно высылает нужные данные в `file.php` каджую секунду.
И еще я использую `getNewMessages()` когда кликаю на каталог и тогда уже внезависимости от того что у меня и так каждую секунду выполняется `getNewMessages()`, функция выполнится еще раз.
В результате я получаю на странице две одинаковых "групы" сообщений.
Почему так происходит?
Дело в том, что невозможно предугадать клик по каталогу и получается так что когда `setInterval()` например на 0.2 секунде выполнит `getNewMessages()`, то на 0.3 секунде могу еще раз её выполнить я своим кликом по каталогу.
Я пробовал создавать `bool` переменную и по клике на каталог ее ставить на `false`, а в `setInterval()` выполнять `getNewMessages()` только тогда когда `bool === true`. Но как я и сказал, функция может выполнится на 0.2 секунде(тогда когда `boll === true`), а только на 0.3 секунде я поставлю `boll = false` и выполню её еще раз по клику.
Это скорее плохая логика заложенная в моей идее? Или все же можна как то обойти это?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте генерировать `uuid` для сообщение, а на клиенте храните список этих `id` в коллекции [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). В таком случае при попытке добавить уже существующий в коллекции элемент, он просто не будет добавлен.